# Wrong input data to a TensforFlow model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I have built a TensorFlow model on Sagemaker and it works fine with real time inference, however I want to use Batch transform functionality and I started to look to input data. I started to debug my model locally with saved_model_cli:

```
saved_model_cli show \
--dir . \
--tag_set serve \
--signature_def serving_default

The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
  dtype: DT_FLOAT
  shape: (-1, 50, 11)
  name: lstm_input:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['dense/BiasAdd:0'] tensor_info:
  dtype: DT_FLOAT
  shape: (-1, 1)
  name: dense/BiasAdd:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I assume, that my input data is called `inputs` as per output above, however, when I run the following code, I get an error

```
saved_model_cli run \
--dir . \
--tag_set serve \
--signature_def predict \
--input_examples 'inputs=[{"":[1.2]}]'
```

**ValueError: "inputs" is not a valid input key. Please choose from "", or use --show option.**

I tried to supply a npy file (`--inputs inputs=batch_transform.npy`), different representations of data, but always the same error.

My model is saved with the following code:

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(  
   tf.keras.backend.get_session(),  
   os.path.join(model_dir, 'model/1'),  
   inputs={'inputs': model.input},  
   outputs={t.name: t for t in model.outputs})
```

I tried TF 1.12 and 1.14 versions, but the outcome is the same.

Any advice?

Comment: I run into the same error. Did you find a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and the solution is easy. You can see from your order that `"--signature_def serving_default"`, which means your `signature_def_default` is `"serving_default"`.

However, when you ran it, you use `"--signature_def predict"`, which is obviously different from `"serving_default"`.

Comment: Thanks, Man! your answer helped me a lot. Thanks again.